Filter function with criteria, but want Exclude specific column from filter function
I have a large array that I want to filter, with criteria, But I don't want one specific column considered
For example:
=FILTER(OCC_Format!A1:BA150000,(OCC_Format!B1:B150000<>"")*(OCC_Format!A1:A150000=TIMS_OCC_Analysis!BX1))
Is there a way I can exclude Column 'D' from the filter without resorting to using  {1,1,1,0,1,1,1....})?
Thank you very much.

It is easy to hardcode and use it manually, but what about doing it dynamically. Try: =FILTER(FILTER(OCC_Format!A1:BA150000,(OCC_Format!B1:B150000<>"")*(OCC_Format!A1:A150000=TIMS_OCC_Analysis!BX1)),SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(OCC_Format!A1:BA1))<>4) also not posting it as an answer since I found you dont care to reply. Thanks.

Also, instead of hardcoding the column index, you can place it in any blank cell.

Huh? Your filter criteria reads (OCC_Format!B1:B150000<>"")*(OCC_Format!A1:A150000=TIMS_OCC_Analysis!BX1).  What exactly do you mean by "exclude Column D from the filter`? Perhaps a sample of your original data (obfuscated to remove confidential information) and the expected results from that data might make things more clear.

With HSTACK and TAKE functions
Instead of filterres place the whole FILTER function
=HSTACK(TAKE(filterres,,3),TAKE(filterres,,-COLUMNS(filterres)+4))
or
=(LET(filt,FILTER(OCC_Format!A1:BA150000,(OCC_Format!B1:B150000<>"")*(OCC_Format!A1:A150000=TIMS_OCC_Analysis!BX1)), HSTACK(TAKE(filt,,3),TAKE(filt,,-COLUMNS(filt)+4)))
